# Is there a better way to optimize for the CSS of my Next.js project?

Tags: css, performance, optimization, next.js, css-in-js

I'm currently working on the project with Next.js, styling with CSS in JS (ReactJSS).

I'm having over 4000 lines of css in a single page when I view the page source, which is considered not very good for the performance. To explain well enough, Suppose I've used *Typography* Component in my *Post details* page which has html with a className like below.

```
<p className={classes.textClass}>Typography</p>
```

I've written some set of css for the textClass (which you see in the page source below) and obviously, I've been passing props from the Post Details page to style the typography. I've been using Typography component 157 times (its a huge page really) and due to css in js, I'm getting 157 unique **.textClass** (because of unique selectors due to using ReactJSS) which is too ugly, when I view the page source. See the example of repeated css in page source.

```
            .textClass-d3-0-2-73 {
              white-space: unset;
              margin-bottom: 0px;
              color: #0c0c0c;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-family: Roboto,&#x27;Noto Sans JP&#x27;;
              text-transform: none;
              text-decoration-line: none;
              padding: 0px;
              font-weight: normal;
              letter-spacing: 0px;
              font-size: 12px;
              line-height: 12px;
            }

            .textClass-d4-0-2-74 {
              white-space: unset;
              margin-bottom: 0px;
              color: #0c0c0c;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-family: Roboto,&#x27;Noto Sans JP&#x27;;
              text-transform: none;
              text-decoration-line: none;
              padding: 0px;
              font-weight: normal;
              letter-spacing: 0px;
              font-size: 12px;
              line-height: 12px;
            }
```

I tried using PostCSS but there was no any improvement rather than distortion of design that was fine beforehand.

So I'm searching for the better technique to optimize the css, and increase the performance. I have no options to run away from CSS in JS but I need to optimize sitting at the same point!

Can we have any technique to purge or optimize the css done with ReactJSS?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't post a code sample of how you describe styles, I assume you use hooks interface with function values, something like this:

```js
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  textClass: (props) => ({
    whiteSpace: props.x ? 'unset' : 'somethingElse',
    marginBottom: props.y ? 0 : 10,
  })
})

const Typography = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props)
  return <p className={classes.textClass}>...</p>
}
```

The problem with using function rules or values in a component that is used many times on the page is that it's hard to optimise.

Every React component instance may pass a different props object and styles can be different for each single element on the page.

In this case I would recommend to avoid function values/rules completely. Instead use a theme from ThemeProvider when possible.

```js
const useStyles = createUseStyles((theme) => ({
  textClass: {
    whiteSpace: theme.whiteSpace,
    marginBottom: theme.spacing,
  }
}))

const Typography = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props)
  return <p className={classes.textClass}>...</p>
}


React.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Typography />
  </ThemeProvider>, 
  root
)
```

If props dependant styling is needed build the class name you need out of multiple separate rules:

```js
const useStyles = createUseStyles((theme) => ({
  h1: {
    whiteSpace: theme.h1.whiteSpace,
    marginBottom: theme.h1.spacing,
  },
  h2: {
    whiteSpace: theme.h2.whiteSpace,
    marginBottom: theme.h2.spacing,
  }
}))

const Typography = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props)
  return <p className={classes[props.variant]}>...</p>
}


React.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Typography variant="h1"/>
  </ThemeProvider>, 
  root
)
```

When doing what I suggested, the output of CSS will be exactly what you would expect.